# browserRouter problem cant execute home component which is in jsx format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i also tried with giving extensions
as follow

```
import home from "./components/home.jsx";

 <Route path="/" element={ <home.jsx />  } />
```

I DIDNT try much i saw you videos extra but didntcame to final conclusion

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The import should probably be `import Home from "./components/home"`, and rendering it should definitely be `<Home />`. Ie, delete the file extension and capitalize it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the home component in Pascal, like Home.

And there's no need for the `home.jsx` change to `<Home/>`